# javascript access image array from php

Tags: javascript, php, turnjs

I am using turnjs to do flip image from SQL images.Images from SQL stored in PHP array. I want to access image PHP array in Javascript and create bloburl for each image. Then, bloburl will be saved in `options`array. Then, I loop through `options`array to:

- create div
- add bloburl to div by `d.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + options['pages'][0] + ")";`
- append div to `<div class="container">`

But, I have problem in accessing PHP image array in Javascript on `var array_sql_imgs = <?php echo JSON_encode($array_image) ?>;`.

It show empty result when I execute `console.log(array_sql_imgs);`. When I tried access `$test_array=array('a','b','c');`. It showing correct result.

```
<?php
//get images from sql in phparray
$array_image            =GetSqlData_Assoc($query_getimg,$db);
/* 
var_dump of $array_image
 array(2) 
{
 [0]=>
  array(1) 
     {
      ["File"]=>blob
     }
 [1]=>
  array(1) 
     {
      ["File"]=>blob
     }
 }
*/
$array_image_encode =json_encode($array_image);

?>

<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width = 1050, user-scalable = no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/turnjs4/extras/jquery.min.1.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/turnjs4/extras/modernizr.2.5.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) =>
    {
        const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
        const byteArrays = [];

        for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize)
        {
            const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
            const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
            for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++)
            {
                byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
        }

        const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
        return blob;
    }
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        var options = {
                        pages:[]
                      };    

                var array_sql_imgs = <?php echo JSON_encode($array_image) ?>;
                console.log(array_sql_imgs);//not display anything
                for(var i=0; i<array_sql_imgs.length; i++)
                {
                    var img             =array_sql_imgs[i]['file'];
                    const contentType   ='image/jpeg';
                    const b64Data       =img;
                    const blob          =b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType);
                    const blobUrl       =URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    options['pages'].push(blobUrl);
                }    
    })
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="flipbook-viewport">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flipbook">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

function loadApp() {

    // Create the flipbook

    $('.flipbook').turn({
            // Width

            width:922,

            // Height

            height:600,

            // Elevation

            elevation: 50,

            // Enable gradients

            gradients: true,

            // Auto center this flipbook

            autoCenter: true

    });
}

// Load the HTML4 version if there's not CSS transform

yepnope({
    test : Modernizr.csstransforms,
    yep: ['plugin/turnjs4/lib/turn.js'],
    nope: ['plugin/turnjs4/lib/turn.html4.min.js'],
    both: ['plugin/turnjs4/samples/basic/css/basic.css'],
    complete: loadApp
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($array_image)` give you?

Comment: @Jeto, I added structure of `var_dump($array_image)` in the post. The blob in that array in unreadable format that consist of symbols like `�C�Y�|o v����/�p҃�����`.

Comment: Do you need those blobs in your JS variable? You'll probably have to `utf8_encode` them to allow `json_encode` to work if you really have to print everything into the variable (it excepts UTF8-encoded characters, you can check `json_last_error_msg()`).

Comment: Yes, I need blob in js variable. So, utf8_encode each of images and stored in array in php before we access in javascript?

Comment: What do you get in `$array_image_encode` after `$array_image_encode =json_encode($array_image);`?

Comment: @Premlatha Yes and any other non-UTF8 part of that array if any.

Comment: dump `$array_image_encode` show`<pre>bool(false)</pre>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried `utf8_encode`, but I get it in javascript as unreadable format. So, I `base64_encode` each of the image and store in new array,`$array_image_encode`. I declare that array as `array_sql_imgs` in javascript  after `JSON_encode` it. I loop through the array and create bloburl for each of images and place it in a array,`options`. I loop through this array to create div element, add background image by using bloburl  and append the element to  `<div class="flipbook" id="flipbook">`. It  works successfully.

```
<?php
$array_image        =GetSqlData_Assoc($query_getimg,$db);
$array_image_encode =array();
foreach($array_image as $key=>$value)
{
    $base64_encode          =base64_encode($value['File']);
    $array_image_encode[]   =$base64_encode;        
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width = 1050, user-scalable = no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/turnjs4/extras/jquery.min.1.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/turnjs4/extras/modernizr.2.5.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) =>
    {
        const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
        const byteArrays = [];

        for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize)
        {
            const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
            const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
            for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++)
            {
                byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
        }

        const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
        return blob;
    }
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        var options = {
                        pages: []
                      };    

                var array_sql_imgs = <?php echo JSON_encode($array_image_encode); ?>;

                for(var i=0; i<array_sql_imgs.length; i++)
                {
                    var img             =array_sql_imgs[i];
                    const contentType   ='image/jpeg';
                    const b64Data       =img;
                    const blob          =b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType);
                    const blobUrl       =URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    options['pages'].push(blobUrl);
                }
                var div_container = document.querySelector('#flipbook');
                for(j=0;j<options['pages'].length;j++)
                {
                        url                             =options['pages'][j];
                        var element                     =document.createElement("div");
                        element.style.backgroundImage   ="url(" + url + ")";
                        div_container.appendChild(element);
                }
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flipbook-viewport">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flipbook" id="flipbook">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

function loadApp() {

    // Create the flipbook

    $('.flipbook').turn({
            // Width

            width:922,

            // Height

            height:600,

            // Elevation

            elevation: 50,

            // Enable gradients

            gradients: true,

            // Auto center this flipbook

            autoCenter: true

    });
}

// Load the HTML4 version if there's not CSS transform

yepnope({
    test : Modernizr.csstransforms,
    yep: ['plugin/turnjs4/lib/turn.js'],
    nope: ['plugin/turnjs4/lib/turn.html4.min.js'],
    both: ['plugin/turnjs4/samples/basic/css/basic.css'],
    complete: loadApp
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```